# Ruta Nginx para buscar carpeta static añade 2 slashes

Tags: python, django, nginx

A la hora de buscar la carpeta `static` en un proyecto Django, el nginx nos muestra este error para todos los archivo de la carpeta `static`:

```
14:43:12 [error] 19#19: *150433 open() **"/var/www/static//js/fontawesome-v531.js**" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

Este es nuestro fichero de Nginx:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;
  server_name _;
  # Redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS with a 301 Moved Permanently response.
  ##return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always;
  access_log /var/logs/nginx/nginx_ssl.access.log;
  error_log /var/logs/nginx/nginx_ssl.error.log;
  
  location /XXXXX {
    #set $upstream_web XXXXX-web;
    #proxy_pass http://$upstream_web:8000/XXXXXX;
    proxy_pass http://XXXXXX-web-service:8000/XXXXXX;
  }
  location /XXXXXX/static/ {
    autoindex on;
    merge_slashes on;
    alias /var/www/static/;
  }
  location / {
     return 301 http://$host/XXXXX$request_uri;
    #proxy_pass http://$host/XXXXX/$request_uri;
  }
}
```

Comment: Has probado configurar ese location sin el slash `/` al final? Lo digo porque posiblemente se lo esté añadiendo automáticamente al traer recursos.

Comment: Si, lo hemos probado y no hace nada,...sigue con las 2 "/", muchas gracias por tu respuesta